# Как убрать все нули из целого числа?

Tags: python

Есть случайное число, допустим `100403`. Из него необходимо убрать все нули, то есть, получить `143`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Думаю что вам подойдет `replace`.

```
q = str(100403)
w = int(q.replace('0', ''))
```

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, гораздо интереснее решать данную задачу без использования строк:

```
n, i, res = 100403, 0, 0
while n > 9:
    n, mod = divmod(n, 10)
    if mod > 0:
        res += mod * 10**i
        i += 1
res += n * 10**i
```